# Regex for sortcode using lookbehind and not to select telephone numbers

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a UK bank sort code (nothing complex, just three pairs of digits, optionally separated by hyphens, spaces).

Which should match against

12-34-56

123456

12 12 12

But not against

07878 787878

So far, I have been using is \d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}

Thank you

Comment: You can use anchors `^\d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}$` Should `12-34 56` match?

Comment: 12-34 56 not expected to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capture group `([-\s]?)` for the first `\s` or `-` and use a backreference `\1` to match the same what is matched the first time.

Use anchors to prevent a partial match.

```
^\d{2}([-\s]?)\d{2}\1\d{2}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `([-\s]?)` Optionally capture `-` or `\s` in **group 1**
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `\1` Match the same as previously captured in group 1
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aqk1aD/1)

**Note** that `\s` could also match a newline.

---

Without anchors, you can prevent 7 or more digits with optional whitespace chars in between by capturing that, and in an alternation match the pattern that you want.

```
(?:\d *){7,}|\b(\d{2}([-\s]?)\d{2}\2\d{2})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yeo1yc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Lxxu6G)

Then you can use re.sub, and in the callback check for group 1.

```
import re
 
pattern = r"((?:\d *){7,})|\b\d{2}([-\s]?)\d{2}\2\d{2}\b"
s = ("12-34-56\n"
            "123456\n"
            "12 12 12\n"
            "07878 787878\n"
            "11 1111\n"
            "1111 11\n"
            "11-1111\n"
            "1111-11\n"
            "11 11-11\n"
            "11-11 11")
 
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "$$$$", s))
```

Output

```
$$$$
$$$$
$$$$
07878 787878
11 1111
1111 11
11-1111
1111-11
11 11-11
11-11 11
```

---

Using the [PyPy regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

```
(?<!\d *)(\d{2}([- ]?)\d{2}\2\d{2})(?! *\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h25w5k/1)

Comment: Its still finding the match in 07878 787878

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper I don't think it is right? https://regex101.com/r/Aqk1aD/1

Comment: I got you but I have a text message so it could be any where inside the text so can not really use start/end. I have been trying without start/end and it still matches to the 07878 787878

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper So you don't want these matches right for `07878 787878` https://regex101.com/r/AXdQqj/1 Do you want the second one `787878`?

Comment: I do not want to match for 07878 787878, since its telephone number

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper So like this, the values are in capture group 2 `(?:\d *){7,}|\b(\d{2}([-\s]?)\d{2}\2\d{2})\b` https://regex101.com/r/yeo1yc/1

Comment: Thanks again but its still matching. For 07878 787878, should not match any thing.

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper It matches, but it is not captured. What do you want to do with the matches? Repace or get them?

Comment: May be `\b\d{2}([-\s]?)\d{2}\1?\d{2}\b`?

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper If you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) perhaps you could use `(?<!\d *)(\d{2}([- ]?)\d{2}\2\d{2})(?! *\d)`  https://regex101.com/r/h25w5k/1

Comment: If found then replace with $$$$ so that no one sees the sort codes

Comment: Looking at it, Its strange that it does not work https://regex101.com but it works in python re package

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper It works in the re package, but in the code I test for the existence of group 1. If it exists then keep it. Else return `$$$$`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will play around and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally capture the digit and spaces before the expected match and apply the custom replacement logic in `re.sub`:

```py
(\d *)?(\d{2}([- ]?)\d{2}\3\d{2})(?! *\d)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/tMMSV2/2). Ignore all matches when the first capture is present.

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##PY7NCsIwEITvfYo1eEhKW@x/EaQPYj1EEzXQ/JCmBxGfPaaluiw73xxmWPNyT61K74U02jqwPDLUOW4VnILJbloaMXJsER4YxKQP8i4@@JzCpScrD@UqBPc7iAdGEIkcn1zIo7xIyyqtmwTyoqzqBqhiAbddzKHt2g6W03bol9s@yKb5ikcqr4yCPILMHlbPBhMQ97/JCfBx4oD2YVACSwOJjBXK4ZW9/wI):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d *)?(\d{2}([- ]?)\d{2}\3\d{2})(?! *\d)")
test = "12-34-56, 123456 and 12 12 12 and 07878 787878"
test = pattern.sub(lambda m: m.group() if m.group(1) else "$$$$", test)
print(test)
```

**Results**: `$$$$, $$$$ and $$$$ and 07878 787878`

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [- ]?                    any character of: '-', ' ' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \3                       what was matched by capture \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```